# Как запустить один playbook на нескольких хостах с разными переменными?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-playbook

Имеем 4 хоста. На каждом хосте необходимо выполнить действия. Например:
Хост А - действия 1,2,3
Хост Б - действия 4,2,5
Хост В - действия 6,7,8
и т.д.
Всё это одним playbook`ом.
Конечный результат должен выглядить так:
Запускаем playbook. Хост А настраивает одно ПО, хост Б настраивает другое ПО и т.д. При этом, между работой ПО на хосте А и хосте Б есть связность сервисов.
Задача усложняется тем, что необходимо передавать во все действия общие переменные, которые были заданы динамически через survey.
Поясните логику выполнения данной задачи.